# Ugly heightForRowAtIndexPath and cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a `UItableview`, which I'm populating with data, using `heightForRowAtIndexPath` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Apparently Apple makes me do things in my code twice.

First I have to calculate the size of my views (for that I have to make them) in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` and then I have to make them again, to add them to the actual view.

I have a pretty complicated view, so it looks double ugly, when you have to write it twice.

Isn't there a better way to do this?

**UPDATE**

This is how my code looks. It's not totally the same, but pretty close. Why in the world does apple make me write this twice?

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSLog(@"heightForRowAtIndexPath");

    //Initiating strings
    NSString *headlineString;
    NSString *subHeadlineString;
    NSString *bylineString;
    if (global.magazine.issues.count==0) {
        return 45;
    }else if(indexPath.section == global.magazine.issues.count+1) {
        //Finding the right issue and article for this row
        Issue *issue = [global.magazine.issues objectAtIndex:global.magazine.issues.count-1];

        //Creating the headline
        headlineString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<span class='bold_style'>FOREWORD</span>"];

        //Creating the subHeadline
        subHeadlineString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [issue.magazine_foreword substringToIndex:100]];

        //Creating byline
        bylineString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<span class='ital_style'>By %@</span>", issue.magazine_byline] capitalizedString];
    }else{
        //Finding the right issue and article for this row
        Issue *issue = [global.magazine.issues objectAtIndex:indexPath.section-1];
        Article *article = [issue.articles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        //Creating the headline
        headlineString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<span class='bold_style'>%@</span>", [article.title uppercaseString]];

        //Creating the subHeadline
        subHeadlineString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [article.main_text substringToIndex:100]];

        //Creating byline
        bylineString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<span class='ital_style'>By %@</span>", article.byline];
    }

    //Creating the labels
    NMCustomLabel *headline = [global.label headLineLabelWithString:headlineString fromTop:30 withWidth:global.screenWidth-60];
    NMCustomLabel *subHeadline = [global.label subHeadlineLabelWithString:subHeadlineString fromTop:30+headline.height+10 withWidth:global.screenWidth-60];
    NMCustomLabel *byline = [global.label articleBylineLabelWithString:bylineString fromTop:30+headline.height+10+subHeadline.height+10 withWidth:global.screenWidth-60];

    //Setting the height of the row
    return 30+headline.height+10+subHeadline.height+10+byline.height+30;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSLog(@"cellForRowAtIndexPath");
    //Preparing the cell
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    //Removing former text views
    for (UIView *subview in [cell subviews]) {
        if (subview.tag == 21 || subview.tag == 22 || subview.tag == 23) [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }

    //Removing and setting tableview border
    [[cell viewWithTag:30] removeFromSuperview];
    UIView *rightBorder = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.width-1, 0, 1, cell.height)];
    rightBorder.backgroundColor = global.lightGrey;
    rightBorder.tag = 30;
    [cell addSubview:rightBorder];

    //Setting the seletion background color on the cells
    UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    bgColorView.backgroundColor = global.extraLightGrey;
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgColorView;
    if (global.magazine.issues.count==0) {
        return cell;
    }else if (indexPath.section-1 == global.magazine.issues.count) {
        //Finding the right issue and article for this row
        Issue *issue = [global.magazine.issues objectAtIndex:global.magazine.issues.count-1];

        //Creating the headline
        NSString *headlineString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<span class='bold_style'>FOREWORD</span>"];
        NMCustomLabel *headline = [global.label headLineLabelWithString:headlineString fromTop:30 withWidth:global.screenWidth-60];
        headline.tag = 21;
        [cell addSubview:headline];

        //Creating the subHeadline
        NSString *subHeadlineString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", issue.magazine_foreword] substringToIndex:100];
        NMCustomLabel *subHeadline = [global.label subHeadlineLabelWithString:subHeadlineString fromTop:30+headline.height+10 withWidth:global.screenWidth-60];
        subHeadline.tag = 22;
        [cell addSubview:subHeadline];

        //Creating byline
        NSString *bylineString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<span class='ital_style'>By %@</span>", issue.magazine_byline] capitalizedString];
        NMCustomLabel *byline = [global.label articleBylineLabelWithString:bylineString fromTop:30+headline.height+10+subHeadline.height+10 withWidth:global.screenWidth-60];
        byline.tag = 23;
        [cell addSubview:byline];
    }else{
        //Finding the right issue and article for this row
        Issue *issue = [global.magazine.issues objectAtIndex:indexPath.section-1];
        Article *article = [issue.articles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        //Creating the headline
        NSString *headlineString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<span class='bold_style'>%@</span>", [article.title uppercaseString]];
        NMCustomLabel *headline = [global.label headLineLabelWithString:headlineString fromTop:30 withWidth:global.screenWidth-60];
        headline.tag = 21;
        [cell addSubview:headline];

        //Creating the subHeadline
        NSString *subHeadlineString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [article.main_text substringToIndex:100]];
        NMCustomLabel *subHeadline = [global.label subHeadlineLabelWithString:subHeadlineString fromTop:30+headline.height+10 withWidth:global.screenWidth-60];
        subHeadline.tag = 22;
        [cell addSubview:subHeadline];

        //Creating byline
        NSString *bylineString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<span class='ital_style'>By %@</span>", article.byline] capitalizedString];
        NMCustomLabel *byline = [global.label articleBylineLabelWithString:bylineString fromTop:30+headline.height+10+subHeadline.height+10 withWidth:global.screenWidth-60];
        byline.tag = 23;
        [cell addSubview:byline];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the screen shot if possible?

Comment: @Rushi See above. Think it's such a funny design decision from Apple to do it this way. Seems a bit retarded.

Comment: You are always free to implement your own view. I'm pretty sure it won't take you long to figure out why it is necessary to know all the height in advance. Or live with the retarded tableview and calculate the cell heights when you create the articles, and cache them in the article object.

Comment: I had the same problem before and what I did was do it slowly and then save all of the heights out to a JSON file, then use that JSON file to quickly add in the row heights after the 2nd run.

Comment: @borrrden Wow. Seems like a lot of work for to do the heights. Matthias Sorry to call them retarded. I'm sure there's a reason for that decision, but it's hard for me to see.

Comment: Well it was either that or suffer a several minute load time (Had about 8500 rows with heights based on image heights that were loaded from disk ><).  Thankfully, that system evolved into a two pane system with the tableview having a standardized row height.  However, for one thing, without knowing all the heights the table view won't be able to accurately display the scroll bars or scroll smoothly.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to follow DRY principles and either add height as a property of the objects you are using as a datasource or add a method to your view controller such as:

```
-(CGFloat)calculateHeightForHeadline:(NSString*)headline andSubHeadline:(NSString*)subHeadline andByLine:(NSString*)byLine
```

Then at least you only have the calculation code in one place.

Alternatively, you could call `[tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]` from your cellForRowAtIndexPath method

Comment: Seems like that could easy the pain a bit. Thanks. What would calling heightForRowAtIndexPath from cellForRowAtIndexPath do though?

Answer (score 2):

You have to do it twice because the table view needs to know how tall it is in total before it draws anything - so it calls the height method for every row before it calls any cell method. With your current code, depending on the number of rows, you may be experiencing a slight delay before the table appears - instruments will show you that it is the height method you're spending time in.

I don't know what you custom label classes do but you may be able to calculate the height without having to create views (which is expensive) by using the string or attributed string drawing and size calculation [UIKit extensions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html), which were created for this exact purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```
heightForRowAtIndexPath
```

Will be called for all your rows. This delegate method returns the height for your rows. As your design required different height for each rows depending upon the condition. Unfortunately you'll have to calculate the row height each time before your row gets created. It's like we are deciding just before drawing the row what will be it's hight.

**There's one way you can avoid this. But I won't advice you to go for it. Because it'll change the design of your `UITableView`.** What you can do is you can decide the maximum height of your row out of all the possible conditions you have. For eg. Let's consider it as 100 pixel. Then you can draw your rest of the cells. However, that'll leave empty space if any of your row is less then 100 pixel. And it'll look shaggy.

Basically, to meet your requirement you'll have to do this twice. No other choice :-(

Comment: Damn. That is sad to hear. And there is not way that I can set the height somewhere else. Like in cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: No you can't set hight inside cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder, why are you creating your custom labels in `heightForRowAtIndexpath`? Why don't you just calculate the size of the text with `sizeWithFont:` or such methods? I think that would be a better way to calculate height of the row. Good Luck!

Comment: That's because I'm using a custom label. Custom font and custom line height. So I have to create them to actually know how tall they are. It gives a little lag when you first open the app. That's the reason I don't really want to calculate height first.